# Did you change your shirt vs Have you change your shirt

Tags: grammar

I told my son we are leaving in ten minutes and asked him to get dressed.

After ten minutes, I ask him:

> **A**: "Did you change your shirt?"
>
> **B**: "Did you get dressed?"
>
> **C**: "Have you change your shirt?"

I am a bit confuse the use of *did* and *have*.

In the context above, I am going to ask him is he already change the shirt.

Which is the correct question?

Comment: All are fine, but remember it's "have you **changed**".  That is the correct "perfect tense" conjugation of "to change" -- I change / I changed / I have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the best answer is C. Notice that ***ed*** is missing —"have you chang***ed***"— because the action finished in the past in a period of time up to now. You mean he changed the shirt and still wearing it. In A, "did you change the shirt?", he may have changed the shirt; that does not mean that he is wearing it now.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a very subtle difference between (A) and (C) in that with (A), the speaker is more interested in when the action took place:

> Have you been to your room? Did you change your shirt?

is asking whether you changed your shirt while you were in your room, whereas

> Have you been to your room? Have you changed your shirt?

is asking two independent questions.

But both are correct.